# Changing lattice coplot strip font

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm trying to change the size of the strip text for `biom` and `days`. I saw other posts suggesting to use `strip.custom()` to change the font size. But it's not working and I can't understand how to fix it. I got this warning:

> Warning messages:
>   In plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :
>     "strip" is not a graphical parameter

```
growth <- c(15, 12, 7, 9, 4, 5, 9, 9)
days   <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
biom   <- c(0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1)
herb   <- c(20, 22, 35, 30, 35, 34, 28, 26)
dfgrowth <- data.frame(growth, days, biom, herb)

library(lattice)
coplot(growth ~ herb | as.factor(biom) * as.factor(days), data=dfgrowth, 
       columns=4, overlap=0, pch=21, bar.bg=c(num=gray(1), fac=gray(0.95)),
       strip=strip.custom(par.strip.text=list(cex=2)))
```

Comment: [?coplot](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/coplot.html) is a function in the default `graphics` package. [?strip.custom](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/lattice/html/strip.default.html) is a function in the `lattice` package. I think that's your primary problem with this solution.